# RecyclerView saving state

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

Anyone have issue that RecyclerView doesn't save scroll position after changing orientation?

```
mMyAdapter = new MyAdapter(context, MyAdapter.generateKey(this), savedInstanceState);
mMyAdapter.setHasStableIds(true);

mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context, VERTICAL, false);
int padding = ResourceUtils.dp2px(context, 8);
mRecycleView.setClipToPadding(false);
mRecycleView.setPadding(0, ResourceUtils.getPixelSize(R.dimen.toolbar_height), 0, padding);
mRecycleView.setOverScrollMode(View.OVER_SCROLL_ALWAYS);
mRecycleView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
mRecycleView.setAdapter(MyAdapter);
mRecycleView.setHasFixedSize(false);
mRecycleView.setOnScrollListener(mScrollManager); // only to hide Toolbar on scroll
```

so i'm not modifed `onDestroy` or `OnSaveInstanceState` methods, only saving adapters data, so when i'm rotating phone, scroll position of `RecyclerView` reseting, some advice?

Comment: at the time RV is restored, does your adapter have contents? Where is this code from, onCreate of your activity?

Comment: yes it has, it's in OnViewCreated in my fragment

Comment: Is it supposed to save scroll position? AFAIK it's up to you.

Comment: it should preserve scroll position so this looks weird to me. If you can share a sample project, I'm happy to look at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood where i had mistake, i used `RecyclerView` from

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //used this instance of recycler view
    mRecyclerView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.recycle_fragment, container, false);
    return mRecyclerView;
}
```

but need to

```
 @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        // instead of searching it after view created
        mRecycleView = ButterKnife.findById(getView(), R.id.recycler_view);
}
```

Problem solved

Comment: I don't think it's because you didn't use "onViewCreated". I think it's because you didn't set an id to the RecyclerView. I think it can be solved by simply inflating a normal layout-xml file that has an id for the RecyclerView.

Comment: @androiddeveloper It seems that the id on RecyclerView is not necessary. However, in my case, I needed to set the LayoutManager on the constructor of the view, not later.

Answer (score 2):

Recently I've improved and created a **FlexibleAdapter** pattern for all RecyclerView. It is able to maintain the state after rotation.

Very simple to use, just copy 2 classes in your common files + some xml in order to enable the selection (Single/Multi) as it was for ListView.

Please have a look at the description and full working example: https://github.com/davideas/FlexibleAdapter